# Org-to-org: certificate-based authentication when calling REST APIs

Tags: apex, integration, single-sign-on, apex-webservice, certificates

I have implemented SSO among two ORGS. I have made a web services class in my service Org. Can I hit that web service from my Identity provider Org using rest callout? I tried it by making a http get request which for which I use following URL pattern **(service Org Url + Urlmap to Web service class)** as a response I got 302 status with updated URL, Too handle this I used following code.

```
while (response.getStatusCode() == 302) {
   request.setEndpoint(response.getHeader('Location'));
    System.debug('END Location isi '+response.getHeader('Location'));
    response = new Http().send(request);
}
```

I was hitting this point **https://cloudce-13a-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/Case/abc** but it redirected to **https://cloudce-13a-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/Case**

finally 404 response returns.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it should be `/services/apexrest/Case/abc`. As written, I'd expect a 404 here.

Comment: @sfdcfox yet after adding this to my HTTP url I am get 401 status error

Comment: SSO does not impact API calls

Comment: @identigral could you please elaborate?

Comment: They're not related to each other. For the purpose of the callout, it doesn't matter how you sign into the org. Pretend you didn't use SSO and go from there.

Comment: @identigral Is it even possible to fetch other Org Data using certificates in Salesforce. As in my scenario I do not create any connected App in my service org and I am not requesting for any authorization tokens before making http request. I am simply trying with existing certificates

Comment: Certificate-only: not possible. Without a connected app - possible but highly discouraged: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269667/mutual-authentication-without-access-token Best practice in your scenario is use a JWT Bearer oAuth flow via Named Creds: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269385/named-credentials-what-is-the-difference-between-jwt-jwt-token-exchange . See [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) for more info.

Comment: @identigral Thanks  finally it works