# How to use Signed certificates to expose REST API in Salesforce?

Tags: rest-api, connected-apps, certificates, ssl, postman

My use case is expose REST API in salesforce using certificate (trying self-signed), should not use OAuth authentication to consume in postman.
Below Steps did but not able to complete.

1. Created Self-Signed certificate, under Certificate and Key management setup.
   [image]
2. Identity Provider updated to use this certificate
   [image]
3. Downloaded after that uploaded the certificate to use it in postman.
   [image]
4. When Click Send button on postman request below HTML response received
   [image]

Is there any step missed in Salesforce (connected app- I can't see other oauth option to create connected app) or postman.
Appreciated all the comments.
Thanks,
Sil

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mutual Authentication without access\_token](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269667/mutual-authentication-without-access-token)

Comment: @identigral, yes tried that too but same error above mentioned i'm getting. not sure what is missing piece.